# Annotation to return null if parameter is null

Tags: java, spring

I have a method like

```
Bar yieldBar(Foo foo) {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.setFoo(foo);
    return bar;
}
```

And I want this call to simply return null if `foo` is null. Is there a way to implement something like

```
@NullPassthrough
Bar yieldBar(Foo foo) {
    ...
}
```

Which would be equivalent to below through some compile time generated wrapper:

```
Bar yieldBar(Foo foo) {
    if (foo == null) return null;
    return yieldBar(foo);
}

Bar yieldBarHelper(Foo foo) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You could go down the way Spring does with AOP, by creating a wrapper-class at runtime. But this would mean one would have to use a DI framework to create and inject beans.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the usage of annotations within Java is purely for syntactic meta data reasons, so for specifying whether a method returns null will not function in this manner.

Another usage would be for specifying additional actions for the compiler when utilising annotations.

Comment: The latter is what I am thinking. Mapstruct, Lombok etc. utilize compile time processing to generate code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any annotation here, and i will say if argument `foo` is null then there is no use of calling `yieldBar` method, you can avoid calling using ternary operator

```
Bar bar = Objects.nonNull(foo) ? yieldBar(foo) : null;
```